# JSON save to file get method

Tags: python, json, selenium, post, get

My code:

```
def saveJSONget(site, code):
        response = requests.get(site)
        json_str = json.dumps(response.json())
        if not response.status_code == code:
            file = open("PATH", 'w')
            file.write(str(response.text) + "\n")
```

I need save to file json all information : headers response and request, request payload. I do not know what function to use, that write to file this elements. And I have a second problem.

How change my method? 
Error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 601, in run
    self.setUp()
  File "PATH", line 13, in setUp
    Class.method(site, 210)
  File "PATHy", line 171, in method
    json_str = json.dumps(response.json())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path
def saveJSONget(site, code):
    r = requests.get(site)
    json_str = r.text
    if r.status_code != code:
        Path("PATH").write_text(r.text+"\n")
```

Comment: Thank you. How I can write - > Request Headers , Response Headers and in POST method - Request payload?

Comment: `r = requests.get(url, headers={'key': 'value'})`  see http://docs.python-requests.org